# Python, Qt, ComboBox, two columns?

Tags: python, sql, pyqt, qcombobox

The question is quite simple, but as far there is a problem with the answer:

I'm using QT with Python and SQL. 
I'm getting some query data: 'select id, department from departments'
I want to create combobox with two columns (id, department), which will display only "department" (department 1, department 2 .. etc), but after selecting, it should return "id".

In other words: i'm looking for same functionality as **displaymember** and **valuemember** for combobox in c#.

I managed to create a Qtableview in Combobox, but one problem creates another (view, reading "id" etc.).
is there any other easier way?

Comment: What library do you make SQL requests with?

Comment: Normally I use PYODBC for SQL connections.
In this case I used the QSqlTableModel for combobox model (as I remember - I don't have the code in front of me now).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the OP notes that it uses QSqlTableModel, then a possible solution to mimic the behavior of C# is to establish the column that will be displayed through the modelColumn property, and then access the corresponding items (id and other fields) using the QSqlRecord associated with the selected row.

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtSql


def createConnection():
    db = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
    db.setDatabaseName(":memory:")
    if not db.open():
        QtWidgets.QMessageBox.critical(
            None,
            QtWidgets.qApp.tr("Cannot open database"),
            QtWidgets.qApp.tr(
                "Unable to establish a database connection.\n"
                "This example needs SQLite support. Please read "
                "the Qt SQL driver documentation for information "
                "how to build it.\n\n"
                "Click Cancel to exit."
            ),
            QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Cancel,
        )
        return False

    query = QtSql.QSqlQuery()
    query.exec_(
        "CREATE TABLE  Departments (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, department TEXT);"
    )

    query.exec_("INSERT INTO Departments(department) VALUES('department1')")
    query.exec_("INSERT INTO Departments(department) VALUES('department2')")
    query.exec_("INSERT INTO Departments(department) VALUES('department3')")
    query.exec_("INSERT INTO Departments(department) VALUES('department4')")
    query.exec_("INSERT INTO Departments(department) VALUES('department5')")
    return True


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.model = QtSql.QSqlTableModel(self)
        self.model.setTable("Departments")
        self.model.select()

        self.tableview = QtWidgets.QTableView()
        self.tableview.setModel(self.model)

        self.combo = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        self.combo.setModel(self.model)
        column = self.model.record().indexOf("department")
        self.combo.setModelColumn(column)

        self.combo.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.onCurrentIndexChanged)

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.tableview)
        lay.addWidget(self.combo)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def onCurrentIndexChanged(self, index):
        column = self.model.record().indexOf("id")
        r = self.model.record(index)
        value = r.value(column)
        print(value)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    if not createConnection():
        sys.exit(1)

    w = Widget()
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Another solution is that based on the data obtained by pyodbc you can build a QStandardItemModel (or another model) where the hidden field is associated with a role that can then be obtained.

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

IdRole = QtCore.Qt.UserRole + 1000


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        d = (
            (1, "department1"),
            (2, "department2"),
            (3, "department3"),
            (4, "department4"),
            (5, "department5"),
        )

        self.model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self)

        for id_, value in d:
            it = QtGui.QStandardItem(value)
            it.setData(id_, IdRole)
            self.model.appendRow(it)

        self.combo = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        self.combo.setModel(self.model)

        self.combo.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.onCurrentIndexChanged)

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.combo)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def onCurrentIndexChanged(self, index):
        id_ = self.combo.itemData(index, IdRole)
        # or
        # id_ = self.model.item(index).data(IdRole)
        print(id_)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = Widget()
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you!
It seems to work as I wanted.
I will implement it tomorrow:)

Comment: Second solution is even better than first :-)