# How to have multiple columns in a QComboBox with a QAbstractTableModel

Tags: python, pyside2

I've seen questions similar to this one but they are aimed at QTableView. This is not using that,, this is just for a dropdown (QComboBox) with a custom QAbstractTableModel, which needs to have 2 columns.

**BIG UPDATE**
(Note: Legacy code has been deleted as this is a better approach on the same question, and legacy code was confusing as hell).

Okay, so trying to catch up with what @eyllanesc explained, I changed this from a QAbstractListModel to a QAbstractTableModel. The result is:

```
class ModelForComboboxesWithID(QAbstractTableModel):
    """Create our basic model"""

    def __init__(self, program, records):
        super(ModelForComboboxesWithID, self).__init__()
        self._data = records
        self.program = program
        self.path_images = program.PATH_IMAGES

    def rowCount(self, index: int = 0) -> int:
        """The length of the outer list. Structure: [row, row, row]"""
        if not self._data:
            return 0  # Doubt: Do we need to return this if self._data is empty?
        return len(self._data)

    def columnCount(self, index: int = 0) -> int:
        """The length of the sub-list inside the outer list. Meaning that Columns are inside rows
        Structure: [row [column], row [column], row [column]]"""
        if not self._data:
            return 0  # Doubt: Do we need to return this if self._data is empty?
        return len(self._data[0])

    def data(self, index, role=None):
        """return the data on this index as data[row][column]"""
        # 1 - Display data based on its content (this edits the text that you visually see)
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            value = self._data[index.row()][index.column()]
            return value
        # 2 - Tooltip displayed when hovering on it
        elif role == Qt.ToolTipRole:
            return f"ID: {self._data[index.row()][1]}"
```

Which I set this way:

```
def eventFilter(self, target, event: QEvent):
    if event.type() == QEvent.MouseButtonPress:
        if target == self.Buscadorcombo_cliente:
           records = ... # my query to the database
           set_combo_records_with_ids(self.program, target, records)
           target.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.test)

def set_combo_records_with_ids(program, combobox: QComboBox, records):
    """Clear combobox, set model/data and sort it"""
    combobox.clear()
    model = ModelForComboboxesWithID(program, records)
    combobox.setModel(model)
    combobox.model().sort(0, Qt.AscendingOrder)
    combobox.setModelColumn(0)
```

The result of this works almost perfect:

- On the dropdown(Combobox) it displays the name.
- If you hover on an item, it displays the ID.

Now I am able to get any data of it this way.

```
def test(self, index):
    data_id = self.Buscadorcombo_cliente.model().index(index, 1).data()
    data_name = self.Buscadorcombo_cliente.model().index(index, 0).data()
    print(data_id)
    print(data_name)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set a QTableView as a view:

```
from PySide2 import QtGui, QtWidgets


def main():
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QtWidgets.QWidget()

    combo = QtWidgets.QComboBox()

    model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(0, 2)
    for i in range(10):
        items = []
        for j in range(model.columnCount()):
            it = QtGui.QStandardItem(f"it-{i}{j}")
            items.append(it)
        model.appendRow(items)

    combo.setModel(model)

    view = QtWidgets.QTableView(
        combo, selectionBehavior=QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SelectRows
    )
    combo.setView(view)

    view.verticalHeader().hide()
    view.horizontalHeader().hide()

    header = view.horizontalHeader()
    for i in range(header.count()):
        header.setSectionResizeMode(i, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Stretch)

    lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(w)
    lay.addWidget(combo)
    lay.addStretch()
    w.resize(640, 480)
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Yeah, I know it can be done with a QTableView (and actually saw this piece of code from you on another answer while looking for this, nice copy/paste haha) but I was wondering if it could also be done without tables.

Comment: @Saelyth why? if you don't want to concatenate strings then the next option is to use QTableView

Comment: @Saelyth Why do you say it is nice to copy and paste? You could point me to the link since if I had found it I would not have published the answer, you will understand that I have many answers (+5000) so it is difficult for me to find them

Comment: I saw it here. 2nd solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59927987/python-qt-combobox-two-columns I see now that they are not exactly the same, but you create the QStandardItems the same way and that confused me, sorry.

Comment: The reason why I don't want a QTableView is because in a perfect scenario I want to only show the "name" of the item, but when clicked on it I want to take the "ID" of it, not the name, and sometimes I want to take both, however I want the ID to be hidden except when you hover on it. (That last part is easy with a `Qt.ToolTipRole` in a model). I found overkill to add a table and I don't understand how to implement that when clicked on a item of the table, it would just take the ID or the name, or both (depending on different situations).

Comment: @Saelyth From what I understand that your ModelClients are obtained based on "records" that shows information from various columns: "reasonable, idunica" and you only want to display the "razonsocial" but you want to obtain the "idunica" when you select an item from the QComboBox? I am right?

Comment: Yes and no. I need to take the ID to perform database searchs, but sometimes I'd want to also just take the "razonsocial" to display it somewhere else without a database search. Ideally, I'd want to be able to take either the "razonsocial", the "id" or both, from a QComboBox (I'd do that programatically. The user have no control over what to get, the user just clicks an item).

Comment: @Saelyth that's exactly what I pointed out, isn't that what my first solution to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59927987/python-qt-combobox-two-columns does?

Comment: @eyllanesc I noticed how you passed a named parameter to `QTableView(selectionBehavior=)` which [isn't listed as one of the constructor parameters](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-6/PySide6/QtWidgets/QTableView.html#PySide6.QtWidgets.PySide6.QtWidgets.QTableView)!  Any documentation on that?  It's a nice trick :)

Comment: @legends2k I don't know if that part is documented in pyside2 but it has a documentation in pyqt so by chance I found that it also works. Note: only works for qproperties